# How to insert certain values ​into a string in certain part

Tags: java, string, text, formatting

I have a special table in my database where I store the message `key` - `value` in the form, for example: `question first` - `How are you, ...?`

Now I want to insert for example a name at the end of the question. I don't need a hardcode, I want to do it through some formatting. I know that there is an option to insert text through `%` or `?1` - but I don't know how to apply this in practice. `How are you,` % `or (`?1`)?`

And what if I need to insert text not only at the end, but also in the random parts:

```
Hey, (name)! Where is your brother, (brothers name)?
```

Comment: String.format("Hey, %s! Where is your brother, %s?", name, brothersName);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert a String into another String using the `String.format()` method. Place a `%s` anywhere in the String where you want and then follow the below syntax. More information [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-format-examples/).

```
String original = "Add to this pre-existing String";
String newString = String.format("Add %s to this pre-existing String", "words");
// original = "Add to this pre-existing String"
// newString = "Add words to this pre-existing String"
```

In your specific situation, you can store the names as other Strings and do this:

```
String name = "anyName";
String brothers_name = "anyBrotherName";

String formattedString = String.format("Hey, %s! Where is your brother, %s?", name, brothers_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
 String.format("Hey, %s! Where is your brother, %s?","Sally", "Johnny");
```

Answer (score 1):

For using the %, first you will need to create another variable of type string in which you store the text you want to print.

Example:

```
String a="Alice";
String b="Bob";
String str=string.format("Hey, %s! Where is your brother, %s?"a,b);
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
Hey Alice! Where is your brother, Bob?
```

You can get more information about this [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-format-examples/)